# Is there a word for the software critical for and specific to a weapon system?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for the software critical for and specific to a weapon system?

Weapon system have software that's critical for their functioning, but what do we call it or them? I am thinking of the specific software that a weapon system has and not the operating system or kernel, because it's shared across a variety of weapon system and not specific to a particular weapon system.

Comment: Perhaps a [**safety-critical system**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety-critical_system) is a phrase that meets your need.

Comment: That includes the hardware. What would you call the software of a safety-critical system?

Comment: Does it have to be a *weapon* system?

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: system-critical software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computer software that is designed to be run on a specific machine or device (such as a weapon), especially a machine that would not normally be thought of as a "computer" is called *embedded software*.

Embedded software is essential for the running of that machine, and is normally specialised for the particular hardware that it is running on. For example a "smart bomb" will have an onboard chip that runs embedded software to control the flight and timing of the bomb and increase the chance of it hitting a particular target.

Embedded software may run with an OS (called an [embedded OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_operating_system)).  For example Linux provides "Embedded Linux", used in set-top-boxes, networking equipment and elsewhere. Embedded software can also be designed to run without a separate OS.

Embedded software designed for weapons is specifically "[military embedded software](http://mil-embedded.com)"

Comment: What about software that runs on top of an operating system? Are all military systems running without an OS?

Comment: Sometimes it can run on an OS.  The details of the embedded systems in military systems is a commersial and military secret. However this question is not a matter for English language learning.